# How to web scrape AJAX Update Panel with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-scraping, updatepanel

I am looking to web scrape a site that has an AJAX update panel. I have been able to login to the website using properly constructed HTTP requests (HttpWebRequest) and I am able to send a POST request to get the contents of the UpdatePanel, but it has placeholder text rather than actual data.

Here is the code where I make the request to get the UpdatePanel data:

```
// Already sent POST request with username and password to get session id, cookie etc
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array. This includes viewstate, eventvalidation etc.
postData = String.Format("ctl00%24ScriptManager1=ctl00%24uxContentPlaceHolder%24Panel%7Cctl00%24uxContentPlaceHolder%24uxTimer&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24uxContentPlaceHolder%24uxTimer");
postData = hiddenFields.Aggregate(postData, (current, field) => current + ("&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(field.Key) + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(field.Value)));

byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.Headers.Add("X-MicrosoftAjax", "Delta=true");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36";
request.Referer = "https://www.example.com/Registered/MyAcount.aspx?menu=My%20account";
request.Host = "www.example.com";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close();
// Get the response.

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
_container.Add(response.Cookies);

using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    // Read the content.
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

response.Close();
```

Here is a summarised version of the response i get:

```
6259|updatePanel|ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_uxUpdatePnl|
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="transtable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <div id="ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_UpdateProgress2" style="display:none;">

                    <div>
                        <img src="../Include/Images/loading.gif" alt="progressImg" />
                        <span id="ProgressMsg" style="font-size: small">Please, wait ... </span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the expected result:

```
2577|updatePanel|ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_uxUpdatePnl|
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_uxMyCards" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th align="left" scope="col" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;height:40px;">Card number</th>
        <th align="left" scope="col" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">Account holder</th>
        <th align="left" scope="col" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">Balance money</th>
        <th align="left" scope="col" style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:110px;">
            <a id="ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_uxMyCards_ctl02_uxManageAccount" href="ManageMyCard.aspx?menu=Manage my card&amp;cno=GgxQxwWICtY4hnlrIZfFzdqc8KMXxVp9" style="font-size:11px;">308425020219083</a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:130px;">
            My Name
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:100px;">
            $1.50
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:110px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:110px;">
            <a id="ctl00_uxContentPlaceHolder_uxMyCards_ctl03_uxManageAccount" href="ManageMyCard.aspx?menu=Manage my card&amp;cno=hkbnmVzj%2ftrs%2fVLXK0rBQhB0enOO%7b4Uf" style="font-size:11px;">308425026724813</a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:130px;">
            My Name
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:100px;">
            $4.04
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px;width:110px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It looks the the page is requested and the response is sent before the data is actually loaded. Is there any way to make a HttpWebRequest wait until all data is loaded before sending a response?

I can post the actual HTTP request if that would help, but it looks pretty much identical to the one made in the browser. And before people jump in and ask, there is no API for what I'm doing, nor is it in any way illegal :)

Edit: Would prefer to stick to HttpWebRequest for this, rather than a 3rd party tool like selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out, I was sending __EVENTTARGET in the HTTP request twice. UpdatePanel loads all data correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this by making HTTP requests to the page since all you'll get is the HTML from the server. The JavaScript in the page will not be evaluated and therefore you won't get the content of the UpdatePanel. One option is making requests to the *handler* which returns the content of the UpdatePanel. Second option is you can use a headless testing tool like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which will actually render the page and execute the JavaScript in the page. The UpdatePanel will update, and you will be able to get the updated content.

Comment: But the javascript must trigger a HTTP request to get the data. That is the HTTP request I'm emulating above. In Fiddler, there is a HTTP request the browser makes and it retrieves the content in the UpdatePanel. When I make exactly the same HTTP request in code, I am not getting anything...